# React Router v4 - Redirect to home on page reload inside application

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux, react-router-v4

I need to redirect to home page when user refreshes other pages inside my application. I am using `React router` v4 and `redux`. Since the store is lost on reload, the page user reloaded is now empty and hence I want to take him back to a page that does not need any previous stored data. I don't want to retain state in `localStorage`.

I tried to handle this in event `onload` but it did not work:

```
window.onload = function() {
    window.location.path = '/aaaa/' + getCurrentConfig();
};
```

Answer (score 7):

You can try creating a new route component, say `RefreshRoute` and check for any state data you need. If the data is available then render the component else redirect to home route.

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

const RefreshRoute = ({ component: Component, isDataAvailable, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      isDataAvailable ? (
        <Component {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect
          to={{
            pathname: "/home"
          }}
        />
      )
    }
  />
);

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isDataAvailable: state.reducer.isDataAvailable
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(RefreshRoute);
```

Now use this `RefreshRoute` in your `BrowserRouter` as like normal `Route`.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/home" component={Home} />
    <RefreshRoute exact path="dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
    <RefreshRoute exact path="/profile" component={ProfileComponent} />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: It's possible to achieve without redux?

Answer (score 0):

It is so amazing that you don't want to keep state of user route map in browser but you use `react-router`!, the main solution for your case is do not use `react-router`.

If you don't use it, after each `refresh` the app come back to main view of app, If you wanna see route map in `address bar` without any reaction use `JavaScript` `history` `pushState`.

Hope it helps you.